# Unexpected EOF while running a script

Tags: python, syntax

I'm having a problem running this python script.

The part of code (line 85) where it gives the error is:

```
{a}Right {b}: {a}git@w4fz5uck5
{b}[{a}Developer{b}] : {a}Escanor 0xTN
""".format(a="\033[92m", b="\033[94m"))
sites = open(input('\033[94m]\033[92m]Sites\033[94m]:\033[92m]'),'r').read().splitlines()
```

Error when I run it:

```
  File "script.py", line 85, in <module>
    sites = open(input('\033[94m]\033[92m]Sites\033[94m]:\033[92m]')),('r').read().splitlines()
  File "<string>", line 1
    dom1-18-04-2020.txt
                      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

What do you recommend that I to do?

Comment: You will probably need to provide more code to determine the issue. Also - The line in the error has an extra closing parenthesis.

Comment: The code in your question appears to be missing the opening `"""`.

Comment: `{a}Mass 0Day Shell Upload {b}- {a}Exploit wp-file-manager {b}6.7
 {a}Right {b}: {a}git@w4fz5uck5
 {b}[{a}Developer{b}] : {a}Escanor 0xTN
""".format(a="\033[92m", b="\033[94m"))
sites = open(input('\033[94m[\033[92mSites\033[94m]:\033[92m '), 'r').read().splitlines()

try:
 with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(300) as executor:
  executor.map(fassa5, sites)
except Exception as e:
 print(e)`